# Scrapy not exporting to csv

Tags: scrapy

I have just created a new scrapy project after ages, and seem to be forgetting something. In any case, my spider runs great, but does not store the output to a csv. Is there something that needs to go into the pipeline or settings files? I am using this command:

```
scrapy crawl ninfo -- set FEED_URI=myinfo.csv --set FEED_FORMAT=csv
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.
TM

Answer (score 6):

Try with this command:

```
$ scrapy crawl ninfo -o myinfo.csv -t csv
```

See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#storing-the-scraped-data (the only difference being they use it to generate JSON data, but Scrapy embarks a CSV exporter: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-format-csv)

Comment: What version of scrapy are you using?

Comment: Well, if you're not bound to this specific version, I'd advise you to upgrade to the last stable one (0.16 IIRC). If for some reason you're stuck with 0.12, there might be a typo in your command ``-- set`` instead of ``--set``. Otherwise, I see no reason why it shouldn't work..

Comment: thanks, but found the error. Scrapy does not like the space in FEED_FORMAT =csv. Sorry, in the above code I typed, the code was written correctly, but not so in my terminal window. BTW, I would like to upgrade, but I have a lot of projects that are working quite well now, and am afraid an upgrade will disrupt things. Will it? And what's the best way to do an upgrade? Thanks again.